# Need help automating scraping a necessary code of a website using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to remove commas from this "Client_name" **dataframe**, but I'm not sure how to? I'm reading you can use regex, but I don't understand how.

[image]

I basically need to remove all of the commas from this data frame. so I just have plain text to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), as follows:

```
data['Client_name'] = data['Client_name'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `replace()` method available in Python, let say's you have a string like  `ansdf,jksd,iou,klk,kkkkk`. so basically a sample code looks like this :-

Sample code:

```
s = 'ansdf,jksd,iou,klk,kkkkk'
a = s.replace(',','')
print(a)
```

Comment: this does not make sense to me, accept and then un-accept . Make sure which answer work for you accept that and do not change it afterwards,  don't do this in future.